# Magento 2 : How to get Additional Information in payment info for custom payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, custom-field, additional-information

I have created custom payment module. Under that module i have display three additional information field.

How to get that additional data from frontend to backend?

[image]

Comment: do you want to Save those field in database ?

Comment: Thanks but i solved the issue.!!

Comment: so describe it here :)

Comment: I have save additional data into Payment additional information field into database using observer and after that in sales_order_view.xml added custom phtml file where i got those additional data.